DomainError with gevfit in Julia Extremes
I fit three extreme value models to annual mamima of precipitation using the Julia library Extremes.

Model 1: stationary
Model 2: non-stationary with years as covariate
Model 3: non-stationary with temperature as covariate

If you use random data, you will experience the error sometimes, but sometimes not. Below is an example, which raises the error.
What causes the error? Does the error express a failed fit? The data looks not like a GEV distribution (see images below). I appreciate any help. Thank you.
Code
using Extremes
using DataFrames


df = DataFrame(
    Year = 1950:2023,
    Precipitation = [0.495651, 0.946367, 0.546022, 0.540578, 0.534175, 0.378817, 0.757754, 0.703223, 0.476006, 0.0851862, 0.171368, 0.425137, 0.495324, 0.378817, 0.873069, 0.50048, 0.946367, 0.500415, 0.00506373, 0.341552, 0.348604, 0.546022, 0.792541, 0.341552, 0.757754, 0.419575, 0.905448, 0.00506373, 0.500415, 0.0823318, 0.143318, 0.792541, 0.104758, 0.853249, 0.789504, 0.129651, 0.50048, 0.789504, 0.946367, 0.792541, 0.546022, 0.878545, 0.792541, 0.905448, 0.513799, 0.0851862, 0.905448, 0.799792, 0.190296, 0.878545, 0.785602, 0.495324, 0.873969, 0.703223, 0.436209, 0.873069, 0.873069, 0.446525, 0.0115384, 0.341552, 0.295142, 0.617508, 0.419575, 0.905448, 0.18504, 0.842249, 0.0510619, 0.785602, 0.799792, 0.789504, 0.418074, 0.540578, 0.789504, 0.171368],
    Temperature = [0.447799, 0.613658, 0.236047, 0.518351, 0.688965, 0.0913033, 0.452838, 0.320158, 0.510309, 0.00790657, 0.00951156, 0.0939902, 0.585119, 0.0913033, 0.829481, 0.797781, 0.613658, 0.930519, 0.441482, 0.579743, 0.41028, 0.236047, 0.557033, 0.579743, 0.452838, 0.261712, 0.359162, 0.441482, 0.930519, 0.467775, 0.751947, 0.557033, 0.839668, 0.755448, 0.0485986, 0.706621, 0.797781, 0.0485986, 0.613658, 0.557033, 0.236047, 0.602792, 0.557033, 0.359162, 0.333738, 0.00790657, 0.359162, 0.870783, 0.932227, 0.602792, 0.309506, 0.585119, 0.915118, 0.320158, 0.994738, 0.829481, 0.829481, 0.301432, 0.0734843, 0.579743, 0.177626, 0.719562, 0.261712, 0.359162, 0.989634, 0.0568152, 0.599304, 0.309506, 0.870783, 0.0485986, 0.421732, 0.518351, 0.0485986, 0.00951156]
    )

fm0 = gevfit(df, :Precipitation)
fm1 = gevfit(df, :Precipitation, locationcovid = [:Year])
fm2 = gevfit(df, :Precipitation, locationcovid = [:Temperature])

Output for model 1: fm0
MaximumLikelihoodAbstractExtremeValueModel
model :
        BlockMaxima{GeneralizedExtremeValue}
        data :          Vector{Float64}[74]
        location :      μ ~ 1
        logscale :      ϕ ~ 1
        shape :         ξ ~ 1

θ̂  :    [0.515300172038444, -1.102433064656073, -0.7512065774413803]



Output for model 2: fm1
MaximumLikelihoodAbstractExtremeValueModel
model :
        BlockMaxima{GeneralizedExtremeValue}
        data :          Vector{Float64}[74]
        location :      μ ~ 1 + Year
        logscale :      ϕ ~ 1
        shape :         ξ ~ 1

θ̂  :    [1.3753214813880437, -0.00043138876235357984, -1.0913167734612388, -0.7743641862377258]

Error
ERROR: DomainError with -2.220446049250313e-16:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.
Stacktrace:
  [1] logpdf(d::Distributions.GeneralizedExtremeValue{Float64}, x::Float64)
    @ Distributions ~/.julia/packages/Distributions/ji8PW/src/univariate/continuous/generalizedextremevalue.jl:195
  [2] _broadcast_getindex_evalf
    @ ./broadcast.jl:709 [inlined]
  [3] _broadcast_getindex
    @ ./broadcast.jl:682 [inlined]
  [4] getindex
    @ ./broadcast.jl:636 [inlined]
  [5] macro expansion
    @ ./broadcast.jl:1004 [inlined]
  [6] macro expansion
    @ ./simdloop.jl:77 [inlined]
  [7] copyto!
    @ ./broadcast.jl:1003 [inlined]
  [8] copyto!
    @ ./broadcast.jl:956 [inlined]
  [9] copy
    @ ./broadcast.jl:928 [inlined]
 [10] materialize(bc::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{…})
    @ Base.Broadcast ./broadcast.jl:903
 [11] loglike(model::BlockMaxima{Distributions.GeneralizedExtremeValue}, θ::Vector{Float64})
    @ Extremes ~/.julia/packages/Extremes/4Tbee/src/structures/AbstractExtremeValueModel.jl:107
 [12] (::Extremes.var"#fobj#39"{BlockMaxima{Distributions.GeneralizedExtremeValue}})(θ::Vector{Float64})
    @ Extremes ~/.julia/packages/Extremes/4Tbee/src/parameterestimation/maximumlikelihood.jl:13
 [13] value(obj::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64, Vector{Float64}}, x::Vector{Float64})
    @ NLSolversBase ~/.julia/packages/NLSolversBase/kavn7/src/interface.jl:19
 [14] update_state!(f::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{…}, state::Optim.NelderMeadState{…}, method::Optim.NelderMead{…})
    @ Optim ~/.julia/packages/Optim/ZhuZN/src/multivariate/solvers/zeroth_order/nelder_mead.jl:263
 [15] optimize(d::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{…}, initial_x::Vector{…}, method::Optim.NelderMead{…}, options::Optim.Options{…}, state::Optim.NelderMeadState{…})
    @ Optim ~/.julia/packages/Optim/ZhuZN/src/multivariate/optimize/optimize.jl:54
 [16] optimize(d::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{…}, initial_x::Vector{…}, method::Optim.NelderMead{…}, options::Optim.Options{…})
    @ Optim ~/.julia/packages/Optim/ZhuZN/src/multivariate/optimize/optimize.jl:36
 [17] optimize(f::Function, initial_x::Vector{Float64}; inplace::Bool, autodiff::Symbol, kwargs::@Kwargs{})
    @ Optim ~/.julia/packages/Optim/ZhuZN/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:91
 [18] optimize
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Optim/ZhuZN/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:83 [inlined]
 [19] fit(model::BlockMaxima{Distributions.GeneralizedExtremeValue}, initialvalues::Vector{Float64})
    @ Extremes ~/.julia/packages/Extremes/4Tbee/src/parameterestimation/maximumlikelihood.jl:15
 [20] fit
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Extremes/4Tbee/src/parameterestimation/maximumlikelihood.jl:40 [inlined]
 [21] gevfit(df::DataFrame, datacol::Symbol; locationcovid::Vector{…}, logscalecovid::Vector{…}, shapecovid::Vector{…})
    @ Extremes ~/.julia/packages/Extremes/4Tbee/src/parameterestimation/maximumlikelihood/maximumlikelihood_gev.jl:121
 [22] top-level scope
    @ ~/Documents/Studium/Master_Hydrologie/Masterarbeit/sub-daily-precipitation-extremes/code/ModelFitting/x.jl:13
Some type information was truncated. Use `show(err)` to see complete types.

Data distribution
Distribution of precipitation:

Distribution of temperature:


It looks to me like whatever the calculation was doing a rounding error combining various components has resulted in an unreasonable tiny negative value for the value of x in the expression x^y.
x^y is well defined for real x >= 0 and any y but when x<0 it fails with domain error unless y = 1/2n+1 or y=n (where n is an integer). [correction from below spotted by @user9712582]
eg. 
 sqrt(-4) will fail domain with error
 sqrt(-4+0im) = 2im  
 cbrt(-8) = -2 

Check the code preceding it to see if this is in fact the case. If it is then clip any tiny negative x values (due to rounding errors) to exactly 0. You should probably still fault anything worse than -1.0e-15 since that might be due to some other algorithmic fault. Possibly a bug in the implementation.
For x<0 x^y is only a real number if y=n or y = 1/(2n+1)
Any other value for y and the answer is a complex number. Julia doesn't understand what you are trying to do but has suggested one option which is to promote the input value x to be a complex number so that the solution domain is expanded to include a valid answer.
I think you would be better served checking that x is non-negative and staying in the domain of reals.
Would need to see the lines of code around the traceback to comment further.

For x < 0, x ^ y is a real number for integer y

@user9712582 well spotted! I had intended to write 1/(2n+1) there. I will amend the answer.
